# python struct pack double

Tags: python, networking, struct.pack

I want to convert -123.456 into a C double for network transmission in python. So I tried this:

```
struct.pack('d', -123.456)
```

I get this as a result:

```
'w\xbe\x9f\x1a/\xdd^\xc0'
```

Obviously there is some hex in there, but what is with the w, /, and ^ sprinkled in there?

Comment: If you want to see them in hex, try this: `struct.pack('d', -123.456).hex(" ")`:

Out[37]: '77 be 9f 1a 2f dd 5e c0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are, respectively, a "w", "/", and "^". Some byte sequences do correspond to ASCII characters.

Comment: Upvoted, it might surprise people, but ASCII chars are numbers too.